# Cannot invoke wordpress's API from outside existing PHP system

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an existing PHP site located on `/var/www/A`, now I want to add a blog module on `/var/www/A/wordpress`. I have installed wordpress below `/var/www/A successfully`. I can visit it via

```
http://localhost/mysite.com/www/wordpress
```

Now What I will to do next is : when a user regist on my site, at the same time create a new user in wordpress, so I need to invoke wordpress's API, and I found one `wp_insert_user`.

I have a User.php and have a login function and I'll `wp_insert_user` code into it.

Fisrt, import API, I added these two lines on the head of my User.php

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/var/www/A/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Second, visit my site via browser. Befor I include two lines, I can via below url to visit logon my site.

```
http://localhost/mysite.com/www/logon.php
```

But, after I added two lines, when I visit my site via

```
http://localhost/mysite.com/www/logon.php
```

it has been redirect or changed to

```
http://localhost/mysite.com/www/logon.php/wp-admin/install.php
```

I notice that I have `wp-admin/install.php` on my url, but I have installed it before below my project `/var/www/A/wordpress`, I can visit it via

```
http://localhost/mysite.com/www/wordpress
```

What a worese, all the style of my logon.php are completely different.

What should I do next ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you check if `/var/www/A/wordpress/wp-config.php` file exists?

Comment: @Kalyan yes, it does exists. I don't know why it redirect to install page and why my site's style are missing